# How to return from a method after another method call has completed?

Tags: java, android, flutter, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

I am building an android app in Flutter where I want to scan for WiFi networks and return the result of the scan when it completes.

The current method which I call via a MethodChannel between my Dart code and the java code is the following:

```
public List<ScanResult> getScanWifiResult(){

if (WifiManager != null && WifiManager.getScanResults() != null && WifiManager.getScanResults().size() > 0) {
    return WifiManager.getScanResults();
}
    return null;
}
```

The method returns List<ScanResult> which is what I want. Now, I need this method to return when `WifiManager.startScan()` has completed.

I have seen people using a `BroadcastReceiver` but I do not know how I can get my method to return only when this BroadcastReceiver has completed. Here is my start for the `BroadcastReceiver` setup.

```
public List<ScanResult> getScanWifiResult(){
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    wifiManager.startScan();

    //Here I need to return wifiManager.getScanResults(); once the BroadcastReceiver is finished. 
    //return wifiManager.getScanResults();
  }


BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    unregisterReceiver(this);
};
}
```

How can I return from the method when the BroadcastReceiver has completed?

I have access to the permissions needed to use WifiManager.getScanResults. I can run both WifiManager.getScanResults and WifiManager.startScan without permission issues.

Update!
I cannot simple wait until there is data returned from wifiManager.getScanResult since I will hold that data of the most recent scan performed. Further, the scan which I start might return null which is also okay. I just want the result on the same scan that I start.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way in anywhere in your code for scanresult you must ask gps location permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

After adding permission in your manifest

```
List<ScanResult> foundedNetwork;
foundedNetwork = wifiManager.getScanResults();
foundedNetwork.SSID;
foundedNetwork.BSSID; 
foundedNetwork.level;
```

Comment: I am able to get the results from wifiManager.getScanResults() just fine. The problem is that wifiManager.getScanResults() returns the results from the latest scan. I want to complete a new scan before calling wifiManager.getScanResults() again.

Comment: you can check the list wheather it has data or null. if it have some data means wifiManager.getScanResult complete

Comment: I cannot do that is this case. wifiManager.getScanResult holds the data from the last performed scan. So it might have data, might also be null. I do not want to have the data from the last performed scan but rather have data from the specific scan I call.